# multiple dlls with multiple classes and global variables in dll

Tags: c++, dll

Good time of day, everyone!

I have some questions about .dll programming in C++, it's rather new for me.

1) If I want to create DLL with a multiple classes, but I still want to create abstract interface for each class, should I create one header file for interfaces, or create separate multiple headers for each abstract class? And what should I do with .cpp implementation of factory functions?

2) If I create object and factory function, and gets a pointer to instance, can I just call "delete" in program when I want to free that memory? I think, that object is placed in dll's pages and there may be some problems. What should I do to properly free memory in this case?

3) I read, that if more than one process binds .dll - dll creates separate individual instances of global variables for each project. Does it right? Then I have two questions if it is true:

3.1) What happens with static members in dll? What if I want to create a singleton manager, can I place it in dll?

3.2) If I have Core.dll and Graphics.dll, Sound.dll and Physics.dll. Core.dll has a global variable (or a singleton manager in my real case). Will the other dlls work with one instance of singleton, or other? (each dll uses Core.dll)

I apologize for my weak English and many questions in one topic :)

Thank you for your attention and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Mostly this is up to you and depends on the scale of the project. On something small it matters little, so keep it simple and have a single header. On larger projects it is best to reduce unnecessary interdependencies as much as possible - so put them in seperate files. You can alwasy create "all.h" which just includes the other things.

2: Yes, if the DLL and the EXE are both linked to the multithreaded DLL CRT. Unless you know what you are doing, always use this as it is the safest and will do what you expect - it results in the exe and dll(s) being able to share the heap as if they were a single executable. You can "new Object()" in the dll and "delete obj" in the exe freely.
NOTE: Mixing different versions of your EXE and your DLL can introduce incredibly subtle bugs (if, say, a class/struct definition changes), so don't do that.

3: Every process has its own independent memory space (unless you specifically do certain things to try to get some shared memory). Processes are not allowed to get to memory of other processes.

3.1: I *strongly* recommend you avoid global state. (Global static-const is OK). Global variables lead to many unexpected and difficult problems, and globals in Windows DLL have a number of additional complexities.  It is far better in the long run for you to have explicit "Initialize/Deinitialze" functions in the DLL that the EXE must call.

But, global statics in a dll are not much different than in an executable ... they get initialized in pretty much the same way when the DLL is loaded. (THings get more complicated when you dynamically load DLLs, but lets ignore that here).

3.2: Yes, they would work with the single instance - but don't do it anyways, you will eventually regret it. Much better to make the initialization explicit because you cannot control the order in which global variables are constructed, and this can quickly lead to very difficult initialization problems.